# why does python not return all the test cases at once? why does the last test case could only be displayed after I pressed enter again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

THE INPUT:

```
4
4
1 -2 3 -4
3
0 0 0
5
1 -1 1 -1 1
6
40 -31 -9 0 13 -40
```

THE OUTPUT when first run the code:

```
YES
[1, -2, 3, -4]
NO
YES
[1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
```

THE OUTPUT when pressing enter again:

```
YES
[40, -31, -9, 0, 13, -40]
```

THE CODE:

```
numberOfTestCase = int(input())

for i in range(numberOfTestCase):

    listLength = int(input())
    aList = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    sumList = 0
    for x in range(listLength):
        sumList = aList[x] + sumList

    if sumList == 0:
        print("NO")
    else:
        print("YES")
        print(aList)
```

**so what does this program do?**
This program is intended to calculate whether or not the sum of the list is equal or not equal to zero and return the list if its not equal to zero.

**input explanation**
first line: indicates how many test cases there is
second line: indicates how many number is in the first list
third line: the first testcase/list
fourth.....n: repeating second and third line for different test cases

**my question: why does python not return all the test cases at once? why does the last test case could only be displayed after I pressed enter again?**

Comment: Your code should work as you expected, try it again.

Comment: I am assuming your code is like  for i in range(numberOfTestCase):  listLength = int(input())  . so assume you gave numberOfTestCase=10, then for each iteration i.e 10 times, you are will enter for loop, ask input , then say yes or no. so if you want all the test cases results at once, save them to a list, return the list after last iteration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not returning all test cases at once because the `if` statement that checks the sum and prints "YES" or "NO" is inside the `for` loop. In each loop iteration, your code does the following:

1. Take the list length as input
2. Take the list values as input
3. Sum the list values in `sumList`
4. Check if `sumList == 0`
5. Print "NO" or "YES" and the list

So, if I understood correctly, a way to solve your problem could be to create two `for` loops which iterate in `range(numberOfTestCase)`. The first takes all the inputs and stores them in `listLength` and `aList`. The second checks if the condition is met and prints the outcome.

```
numberOfTestCase = int(input())

listLength = []
aList = []

for i in range(numberOfTestCase):

    listLength.append(int(input()))
    tmpList = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    aList.append(tmpList)

for i in range(numberOfTestCase):
  sumList = 0
  for x in range(listLength[i]):
      sumList = aList[i][x] + sumList

  if sumList == 0:
      print("NO")
  else:
      print("YES")
      print(aList)
```